# Matlab, FFT and Centroid Frequency

Tags: matlab, fft, frequency, spectral, centroid

I have taken the FFT  in Matlab in this given way.

```
X=fft(t); % Take Fourier Transform
T=abs(X); % Take real parts of transform
T=T(1:n/2);
```

I'm interested in finding the centroid frequency of this plot. I understand that the centroid freuency is given as:

[image]

Where x(n) represents the weighted frequency value, or magnitude, of bin number n, and f(n) represents the center frequency of that bin.

Now I am tempted to say that f(n) are the values from T in my script, but those are the absolute values of the imaginary and real components of the FFT and so I don't know how to find the x(n) which is supposed to be a weighted frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that `f(n)` is the centre-frequency of the n-th bin; this is nothing to do with your data.  It's simply a function of your sampling frequency:

```
f(n) = n * fs / N
```

You can of course, factor this out in your above equation:

```
centroid = (fs / N) * SUM { n x(n) } / SUM { x(n) }
```

It sounds like `x` is what you've called `T` in your code.

Comment: @ Oliver Charlesworth, may I ask what is N? is it length of the signal?

Comment: @ Oliver Charlesworth, could you help in this as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463543/matlab-centroid-frequency-total-power